# Formating the numbers appearing as text in a boxplot in ggplot. Explaining the positioning of means outside the boxplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, rounding, mean, boxplot

I have developed code in ggplot for a boxplot that displays the mean --calling a custom function.  The code is the following:

```
fun_mean <- function(x){
  return(data.frame(y=round(mean(x), digits = 3),label=mean(x,na.rm=T)))}
ggplot(my_data, aes(x = as.factor(viotiko), y = pd_1year, fill = as.factor(viotiko))) + geom_boxplot() +
  labs(title="Does the PD differ significantly by 'Viotiko' group?",x="Viotiko Group", y = "PD (pd_1year)") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,0.05))  + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="point",colour="darkred", size=3) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = fun_mean, geom="text", vjust=-0.7)
```

The boxplot outputted is the following:

[image: boxplot displaying means]

As you can see, although I have rounded the means to contain only 3 decimal digits, they appear long and clutter the plot.

What should I do to limit the digits displayed to only 3?

Moreover, I am puzzled by the fact that the means appear outside the distribution depicted by the boxplots in the majority of the groups.  How could this be interpreted?

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps `label = round(mean(x,na.rm=T), 3)`?

Comment: To answer your second question (and as a general rule when asking questions on SO), please, provide an [mcve], e.g., the result of `dput(my_data)`. Otherwise it may happen that your question will be downvoted or closed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I faked up some data to reproduce this - in the future you should do that yourself before posting:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)

n <- 100

my_data <- data.frame(viotiko=sample(0:8,n,T),pd_1year=exp(rnorm(n,-4.5,0.8)))

fun_mean <- function(x){
  y = mean(x,na.rm=T)
  return(data.frame(y=y,label=round(y,3)))
}

ggplot(my_data, aes(x = as.factor(viotiko), y = pd_1year, fill = as.factor(viotiko))) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(title="Does the PD differ significantly by 'Viotiko' group?",
                               x="Viotiko Group", y = "PD (pd_1year)") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,0.05))  + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="point",colour="darkred", size=3) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = fun_mean, geom="text", vjust=-0.7)
```

Yielding this:

[image]

As for your question about why the mean is falling outside the 0.25-0.75 quartile, that is quite common - and to be expected - for long tailed data,even if it does seem a bit counter-intuititive. In this case I used a log-normal distribution and I had 3 of 8 mean values outside those quartiles.